# remove a prepended tag

Tags: jquery, html

in the first snippet i add a div element to other elements.
The div is added, the item image is showing.

The second snippet remove a item from the items div. 
Also without problem.

```
/* add item */
$('.add-to-session').on('click', function() {
    var this_obj = $(this);
    var data_cl_item = $(this).data('cl-item');
    var data = {
        'action': 'add_to_session',
        'item': data_cl_item
    }
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if(response != "") {
            $('.no-items').hide();              
            $('.session-items').prepend(response);
        }
    });
});

/* remove item */
$('.session-item-image').on('click', function() {
    var this_obj = $(this);
    var item_id = $(this_obj).data('delete');
    var data = {
        'action': 'delete_from_session',
        'item_id': item_id
    }
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {          
        if(response == "200") {             
            $('.cl-session-item-'+item_id).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem:
I cant remove FRESH ADDED items without page reload.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for dynamic element just `.click()` Or `$(".Element").on("click",function(){})` Wont work.

Use

```
 $(document).on('click', '.YourElementClassWhichWillBeClicked',                
 function() {
  //Your code
 });
```

Why ?
Because , when you write it may be possible that the Element was Not present when DOM , HTML was rendered at first.

You have many elements that get rendered on some event etc.So those are dynamically created elements in HTML , not there when DOM was loaded.

Now see , everytime you click Anywhere  , you are first clicking on `document`, right , So delegates dynamically generates and attaches event to that element by finding it at `Runtime`. So delegates is the way to tackle dynamic element as per your question.

**The issue is you are attaching `on()` event to dynamically added element. you should use delegate in your case**